# Apply free Fedex shipping (all types) to an order in Magento in the admin section

Tags: magento, magento-1.8, fedex

I would like a way to apply free fedex shipping to orders in the admin section. It should be able to zero out the shipping on all fedex shipping types (ground, express, etc).

I am currently able to set free shipping on ground by having a Shopping Cart Price Rule to check if the order contains an item called Free Shipping with the sku 'freeshipping', but this only applies on ground shipments. This is set in Config->Shipping Methods->Fedex->Free Method=Ground

What is the best approach for accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by configuring a Shopping Cart Price Rule, so you were definitely on the right track.

Create a new rule by going to Promotions -> Shopping Cart Price Rules -> Add New Rule. While editing your rule:

- Click the "Conditions" tab. Click on **ALL** and change this option
  to **ANY**. For each shipping method that you would like to apply
  free shipping to, click the green circle to add a new condition and
  select "Shipping Method" followed by the specific method that you
  would like to make free.
- Click on the "Actions" tab and change the "free shipping" option to
  "For Shipment With Matching Items".
- You will likely need to change a few more fields in the "Rule
  Information" tab such as the duration of this promotion, sites, customer groups, etc.

Hope this helps. Let me know if there is anything I can clarify.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I tried doing, but the free shipping only applies to the selected Fedex Free Method in Config->Shipping Methods->Fedex->Free Method. If 'None' is selected, it applies to none. This seems to be the selector restricting which fedex shipping method can be free. Is there a way to have an 'All' in that selector, and then set a very high minimum order amount?

Comment: I ended up adding a shipping type to getCode in Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Fedex called FEDEX_ALL_FREE, and then overrided _updateFreeMethodQuote to set the price to 0 on all of the rates if $freeMethod=='FEDEX_ALL_FREE'